# Need to Access the Item ( android:id="@+id/nav_camera")

Tags: java, android

The main XML 
Need to access the Item click via id (nav_camera)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Camera" />
</group>
```

This s Xml file
Try to access via following code.

```
public class Camera extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
Menu nav_camera =(Menu)findViewById(R.menu.nav_camera);
}
```

}

need to access Item(nav_camera) via id;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_landing_page, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);

    MenuItem pinMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemID);
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

or please add more description on what do you want to do so I can provide more specific answer